# Hint needed: If f admits directional derivatives, then $D_{\lambda v}f(a) = \lambda D_v f(a)$

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

$f:A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, a\in int(A)$, and f admits directional derivatives $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I need to prove that $D_{\lambda v}f(a) = \lambda D_v f(a)$  $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $f$ was differentiable, proving it using the properties of the scalar product would be easy. But since having directional derivatives doesn’t imply differentiability I can’t use that here.

I’ve tried using the definition of directional derivatives but I’m not sure if I can “take $\lambda$ out” of the limit.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. For example, what is your definition of $D_{\lambda v}f(a)$.

Comment: Let $g_v: I\to  \Bbb{R} $ be defined as $g_v(t) =f(a+tv)$ (where I is some small open interval around the origin). Then the directional derivative is nothing but $D_vf(a) =g_v'(0)$. Can you try to figure out the relationship between $g_v$ and $g_{\lambda v} $? Hence how are their derivatives at the origin related? The basic single-variable chain rule is relevant. (or of course one could just directly deduce this by writing out the full limit definition... since in this case it is easy enough).

Comment: $D_{\lambda v}f(a)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a+t\lambda v) - f(a)}{t}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I shall be assuming $\lambda \neq 0$.) As you've mentioned, we have
$$D_{\lambda v}f(a) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a+t\lambda v) - f(a)}{t}.$$
By properties of limits, we have
$$D_{\lambda v}f(a) = \lambda \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a+t\lambda v) - f(a)}{\lambda t}.$$
We can make the substitution $t \lambda = s$ to get
$$D_{\lambda v}f(a) = \lambda \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f(a+ s v) - f(a)}{s}.$$
The limit on the right is simply $D_{v} f(a)$, as desired.